# LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'opencv_calib3d248d.obj'

Tags: c++, opencv

I am working on VS 2010 with OpenCV 2.4.8 . I'm new to this and doing a simple image display program. I included all the libraries in 
"properties->linker->input->additional dependencies" & also in C/C++ directories. Also I have provided with path, but I am still getting the following error:

> LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'opencv_calib3d248d.obj'

I found no solution on the web, can someone help me?

Comment: Did you follow these steps [for setting up opencv for Visual Studio](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_visual_studio_Opencv/windows_visual_studio_Opencv.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following library names to the Project Properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependancies

Ofcourse the last *248 refers to the version of specific application. Mine is 248, so the files look like opencv_features2d248d.lib, if your version is 249 change the value to opencv_features2d249d.lib

---

> opencv_features2d248d.lib
>
> opencv_flann248d.lib
>
> opencv_gpu248d.lib
>
> opencv_highgui248d.lib
>
> opencv_imgproc248d.lib
>
> opencv_legacy248d.lib
>
> opencv_ml248d.lib
>
> opencv_nonfree248d.lib
>
> opencv_objdetect248d.lib
>
> opencv_ocl248d.lib
>
> opencv_photo248d.lib
>
> opencv_stitching248d.lib
>
> opencv_superres248d.lib
>
> opencv_ts248d.lib
>
> opencv_video248d.lib
>
> opencv_videostab248d.lib